# understanding "slice" in console in Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am deconstructing a carasoul plugin called Unslider.js , and i have a difficulty understanding a little peice of code , so here i am on stack overflow .

My difficulty is understanding the below line :

```
target = li.eq(index);
```

lets analyse that ,

**target** is a variable .

**li** is an object , actually let me clarify what li is , previously in the code using the find() method in Jquery which returns a set of child elements so basically li is a set of `<li>` elements .

next , **eq** is often used to filter element further .

**index** is ofcourse the current element (i am not sure about this interpretation though) .

so basically i understand the below line :

```
        target = li.eq(index);
```

target is the current li element, am i right , i think so .

well lets move on to what my real difficulty is , when i console.log(target) , i get the following results :

```
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(3,4)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { 0: <li>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(1,2)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { 0: <li>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(2,3)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(3,4)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { 0: <li>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(1,2)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { 0: <li>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(2,3)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(3,4)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { 0: <li>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(1,2)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { 0: <li>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(2,3)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(3,4)" } unslider.js:286
"taget is" unslider.js:285
Object { 0: <li>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: <div.banner>, selector: ">ul >li.slice(1,2)" }
```

now what does this line mean ..

```
selector: ">ul >li.slice(3,4)",
```

i mean the `slice(3,4)` part and that part keeps changing with different values !! it would be great if somebody could come along and explain what that is .

Thank you.

Alexander.

Comment: it's helping you understand the DOM tree that you use to access this element, the parent is `>ul` and it's one of the child nodes `li` which happens to be `slice(indexFrom, indexTo)` since it could potentially be several li's in one target as would be the case if you were to have just asked for all li's instead of just one. So basicially the 3 is the 3rd index or third child of that parent ul. Basically you're starting at your last child (3), then moving to the first child (1), then (2), repeat.

Comment: The [.selector](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property of the jQuery collection object was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9 and was considered an 'internal', meaning that it was not part of the public API shouldn't be relied on it in any of your code, as it was subject to change.

Comment: @DaveGoten that will help clear some confusion . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Slice is used to return a subset of an array. In this case the values are always separated by one, so it will return an array of a single element.

```
var li = ['a','b','c','d'];
console.log(li.slice(2,3));
>  ['c']
```

So it's just a way to select one element from the list, but generally applicable to selecting a range of elements as well.